# Cannot ping CentOs 6 vm on ProxMox

Tags: centos, routing, ping, proxmox

I'm new here and i have a fresh proxmox system and a CentOs6 vm and 2 ip's ... one for proxMox and one for centOs vm

Working stuffs:

- ping to proxMox's ip
- ping from proxMox terminal
- ping from centOs terminal
- ssh login on centOs & proxMox
- browser access to proxmox and whm ( whm/cpanel is installed to centOs vm )

Not working :

- ping to centOs ip/hostname from another machine

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual machine  must be in same network. Please set network adapter to bridge mode.

Comment: it s set to bridge vmbr0 - model virtIO

Comment: but this vm have his own public ip address ... so i can reach from outside e.g. ssh user@vm.ip

Comment: Try disabling firewall in virtual machine

Comment: iei it works :) but i can't leave firewall off ... i set basic iptables for some ports ... i need to open a specific one to get reached?

Comment: You should allow icmp service for working ping

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT